# Is there a way to check if lotus notes client running or open using C# .NET

Tags: c#, lotus

Is there a way to check if lotus notes client running or open using C# .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lotus Notes has several processes, I suggest you check for nlnotes.exe and notes2.exe. If one of these exists, Notes is running (version 8+)

Comment: I tried below code. its giving "{System.Diagnostics.Process[0]}" even though lotus notes client not opened. Process[] lnotes = Process.GetProcessesByName("nlnotes.exe")

Comment: Why don't you try something like that: http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-getprocesses
Walk through a loop all processes currently running and check for the names? 
For testing you first could see and check which processes are running when Notes is started and then modify the script to match your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the process name for Lotus Notes Client would be - but you absolutely should be able to.

Here is a sample for finding notepad.

```
Process[] notepads = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
```

If the Process[] is empty, it means no match was found.  If it's not empty, it means an instance is running on the local machine.

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx